# C# What's the difference between using these two switch operations?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I know two ways with switch statement to write logic what I want to implement in C#. They are:

```
int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
string timeWord = string.Empty;

// first
switch (hour)
{
    case int x when hour < 12:
        timeWord = "morning";
        break;
    case int x when hour < 18:
        timeWord = "afternoon";
        break;
    case int x when hour < 24:
        timeWord = "evening";
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Another fine mess you got us into");
}
// second
switch (hour)
{
    case < 12:
        timeWord = "morning";
        break;
    case < 18:
        timeWord = "afternoon";
        break;
    case < 24:
        timeWord = "evening";
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Another fine mess you got us into");
}
```

These variants work identically and I know they represent relational pattern. But is there a difference which variant will I use in my program?

Comment: "These variants work identically" <--- I think you already answered your own question.

Comment: The 2nd is available only from C# 9.0, I guess it was offered to perform similarly to the the 1st, with a shorter syntax.

Comment: An optimizing compiler will give same results.  Some organizations have created coding standards where certain source code standards are required.  In some cases one coding style may require first or second case.  But if you are not required to use coding styles it doesn't make a difference.  What is important is for other people to maintain your code if you leave the company.  So you want to make sure your code is easily understood by others.

Answer (score 1):

The second way will be optimized to do binary search but the first way not (in the current version of compiler).

It is not so important for `switch` with three cases, but may improve performance for large `switch`.

[The second way](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) is equivalent of something like this, which in the worst case results in two comparisons, in general has `O(log(casesCount))` complexity:

```
if (hour < 18)
  timeWord = hour < 12 ? "morning" : "afternoon";
else if (hour < 24)
  timeWord = "evening";
else
  throw ...;
```

[The first way](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKAwGYACbUgYVIG9DSHyyMAWUgWQAoBKW+xgbASkAFgHsArgCdSAXlIARCAgCmAFShgVAOgByYgO7aAEpKkBufgIYYcABlIJNKgOpipAEznl72gKJgAA4IAJ6WBFbWAPRRpABmUFIAzgiRAkkGUAgAxiKknOLS3GmMdATWFaTZEEkqpEKkAB6kBiIqMKJmpAA8pDhYICWVjE5abp7eAERg7jCwAOaT4cPDwFIqEADWyysM1bX1MMLNre2d0j19AByD5bvWo67uXvKTEHGqUjBiYjBLQys1httgCBPs6g0Tm0OoUZL0sCxbvcHs5xi9SJMVAA3doLf53ZEMIFbHa7DwqOIQCQoJCgyoIERSQykGAqAykPyNbIqYJQX6cSYAQW+DJUMgSrNIWiSSVIIUkpHmYmEEllQjEk24pOsAF9InqCDqgA==) checks all conditions sequentially, which in the worst case results in three comparisons, and has linear complexity:

```
if (hour < 12)
  timeWord = "morning";
if (hour < 18)
  timeWord = "afternoon";
if (hour < 24)
  timeWord = "evening";
else
  throw ...;
```

But a much better way to write this `switch` is to use [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) rather than *statement*, much shorter and compiles like the second way:

```
var timeWord = hour switch {
  < 12 => "morning",
  < 18 => "afternoon",
  < 24 => "evening",
  _ => throw new Exception()
};
```